# Translate English to some other Language in RAD or Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, rad

I have written comments in English in my Java files but now my client wants it in Spanish, So is there any tool/Plugin available in RAD or ECLIPSE IDE to convert all the comments in other language. I am using google translator to convert comments manually.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any plugin like that. First, I would make sure the client really really wants this. Doing an automatic translate of highly technical text will not give a very good quality. I question if they will be usable at all, do a test translate of a couple of comments first to get approval.

If they really want something that is usable someone with language and technical skill would have to manually translate everything, which would take time/money.

But, if I had to do it, I would take the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24040111/207764) to automatically launch a web browser from Eclipse, and use the URL to google translate, `https://translate.google.se/#en/es/${selected_text}`, should work.

If the codebase is large and the comments can be easily found, such as a javadoc, I would write some script to automatically handle this. Google translate has an API you can use. See [REST API doc](https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/using_rest)

Comment: Thanks Fredrik, Google translator API is not free of cost so searching for some other freeware.

Answer (score 1):

Every now and then a developer has to work on a code base that is in a language that is unknown to him. In this case, he would need to copy variable, class, method names to Google Translate to see what they actually mean.

The Source Code Translation in Eclipse tries to help such developers, by providing a popup with the translated words, when hovering the mouse over them. The plugin is able to handle compound words or phrases that use camelCase or underscore "_" as separation methods.

For the plugin to work, a properties file containing the word to be translated, and the translation needs to be created and added from the Preferences section of the plugin.

**Add this URL to your Eclipse Installation to reach this solution's update site.**

https://github.com/Testehan/TranslationPluginInstall/raw/master

Answer (score 0):

In External Tools Configurations

Location : `${system_path:cmd.exe}`

Arguments : `/C start "" "https://translate.google.com/#en/fr/${selected_text}"`